# Why does a CDN server need my IP address to let me download a video?

Tags: web-application, content-security-policy

I used browser developer tools to get the source page of a video from a webpage.

When I try to open the full URL containing the video, I see my public ip address is contained in that URL.

Changing that ip address to some other value, or omitting the ip address altogether does not let me download the video. I save the page, but get an empty .mp4 file.

Also, I found out that the video URL was contained inside a javascript section, not the html section. Does this have any relevance to what I am asking?

Comment: Also in related networking 101, why does anyone need my IP address so we can establish direct, unproxied IP communications between two computers.

Comment: @TildalWave: http://cdn2b.video.pornhub.phncdn.com/videos/201406/18/28303281/vl_720P_704.0k_28303281.mp4?rs=200&ri=2900&ipa=116.193.130.20&s=1456627404&e=1456634604&h=07f7a04d57534ec799fbb2c6bbf23ba5     ---------   If you can find info about the cdn from this URL, please use it. As you can see, My public ip address is being shown in the URL. Monkeying around with the parameters after the URL results in failure. What things are at play here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CDN server does not really *need* your IP address in the URL. Your computer already sent your IP address in the IP packet when making a TCP/IP connection to the CDN's server.

Since the CDN would already have your IP address from the TCP connection, then why is there an IP address in the URL?

It's most likely to prevent abuse. The IP address is evidence that the client understands and runs Javascript, which is easy for regular users but is likely to stump simpler bots. The CDN might also use it to detect proxies that don't declare the original IP address in the Forwarded header.

Comment: Yes, I believe you are right. Abuse prevention. As I mentioned I tried monkeying around with the URL for the video, but all were failure cases. Thanks a lot!